# How to vertical align the following content without using table cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
img {
  display: table-cell;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /> <span>Test</span>

</div>
```

It seems to work but I want to know if there is an alternative without using table. If I don't use table and just use:

```
span {vertical-align: middle;}
```

It doesn't work!

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vertically align the image and the span.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /> <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img,
span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc2jn8vk/

Comment: Thanks a lot it finally worked. I will accept it as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: Note this will center the image with the line box. But the span will still have `vertical-align: baseline`, so the text won't not centered with the line box. To center the image with the text, the `span` also needs `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 0):

[**MDN's docs on vertical-align**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) states:

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

So, alternatively you could set the span to be a `display: inline-block`, and the property will work (if the span has a height defined)

```css
div {
  
}
img {
  
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /> <span>Test</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do away with the tables altogether. You can check out

`display: inline-block;`

By using this on the `img` & `span` you can set vertical alignment via std css.

Here is a codepen example: http://codepen.io/sixthcore/pen/pvdMyp

A quick notice to remove any white space in the stacking using this the hack is to use the font-size: 0px value on the surrounding div. This does mean that you will need to specify the font-size: for the span.

this solution does not require the usage of tables. Hope that helps.